# Processing - the picture is not loading because X was not used

Tags: java, animation, processing

I am trying to make an animated logo picture but it's not working because it says the "X" variable is not used. Could anyone lead me in the right direction? the picture attached is the guidelines.

[image: the guidlines]

```
PImage gradient;
PImage logo;

void setup(){
 size(792, 150);
 background(0);
 gradient = loadImage("gradient.jpg");
 logo = loadImage("BRICKSxMORTAR_logo_transparentX.png");
 }

void draw(){
 for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
float x =random(width);
loadImage("gradient.jpg");
ellipse(40,40,40,40);{
 loadImage("BRICKSxMORTAR_logo_transparentX.png");
}


}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You already loaded the images in `setup()`, no need to continously reload them multiple times per second in `draw()` (e.g. remove `loadImage("gradient.jpg");` and `{loadImage("BRICKSxMORTAR_logo_transparentX.png");}` from draw()).

If you need to display a loaded image simply use [`image(yourImage, x, y)`](https://processing.org/reference/image_.html) e.g. `image(logo, 0, 0);` at the end of `draw()` (probably outside the `for` loop)

It doesn't look like you're using the "user-driven animation pattern from the last lesson" the homework assignment requires.

If you're sourcing pixels you're probably going to need PImage's [`get()`](https://processing.org/reference/PImage_get_.html) or [`pixels[]`](https://processing.org/reference/PImage_pixels.html) (after calling `loadPixels()` once in `setup()` after loading the image).